# System.NullReferenceException when trying to set ItemsSource

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ado.net

System.NullReferenceException when trying to set ItemsSource (ADO.NET EF)

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = OdbConnectHelper.entObj.работники.ToList();
```

I checked App.Config and everything seems to be connected correctly

```
<add name="qualificationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.qualification.csdl|res://*/db.qualification.ssdl|res://*/db.qualification.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress01;initial catalog=qualification;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress01;Initial Catalog=qualification;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I can't fix the error in any way. I have another program with exactly the same pieces of code and it works perfectly, but this one doesn't.

Comment: Put a break point on the line of code that throws the exception. When it gets hit, look at each property and see which one is `null`. `entObj` and `работники` are good candidates.

Comment: dataGrid.ItemSource is null [image link](https://imgur.com/a/kqMOVF9) (workers = работники)

Comment: That is NOT going to throw the null Reference Exception. `dataGrid.ItemsSource` is getting assigned a value as it is on the left-hand side of the “=”. In other words, the code is “assigning a value” to a currently `null` value … which is OK. The exception means you are trying to “use” something that is `null` and my previous comment points to two likely candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I forgot to write `OdbConnectHelper.entObj = new qualificationEntities();` in MainWindow after initialization.